# Everything between two sentences with parentheses

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

I'm struggling with this one in Oracle.

I want everything between "Command (" and ") executed by "

String:

> Command (grep ) ex.txt) executed by user1@server03 as root@server03

Desired result:

> grep \) ex.txt

I'm testing de regex on this site: https://regex101.com

This solution work on the site but, do not in my select:

> (?<=Command ()(.*?)(?=\e*))

Select used:

> select
>          REGEXP_SUBSTR(MSG,'(?<=Command ()(.*?)(?=\e*))',1) as command
>   from COMMANDS

The expression **(([^)]+))** works, except when there is a other ")" inside the string. That's why I'm trying the between strings approach instead of just inside parentheses.

Thanks a lot

Comment: A simpe `Command \(( .*?)\) executed by` should work, as well as `(?<=Command \()( .*?)(?=\) executed by)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions150.htm#SQLRF06303) to match the entire `Command (...) executed by` expression and extract the required part using a capturing group:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0fb728/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Data ( Str ) AS
SELECT 'Command (grep ) ex.txt) executed by user1@server03 as root@server03' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( Str, 'Command \((.*?)\) executed by', 1, 1,'i', 1 ) AS Match
FROM Data
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0fb728/1/0)**:

```
|         MATCH |
|---------------|
| grep ) ex.txt |
```

Comment: Greedy operator `.*` will work equally well as the reluctant `.*?` for this particular case.

Comment: `.*?` was deliberately chosen for the case when two strings are merged into one - i.e. `'Command (A) executed by ... Command (B) executed by ...'` In which case it will only get the `A` result rather than `A) executed by ... Command (B` (and could use the occurrence parameter of the function to get the `B` result if required).

Answer (score -1):

`\(.*\)` - this will work.

```
>>> s
'Command (grep ) ex.txt) executed by user1@server03 as root@server03'
>>> re.search(r'\(.*\)', s).group()
'(grep ) ex.txt)'
```

Comment: But would fail on: `'Command (grep ) ex.txt) executed by (user1@server03) as (root@server03)'`